# PHP Info Missing

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, global-configuration

Having some (phpmailer) mail issues today with my site so I though of checking System > System Info > Php Info and it's blank. No info at all.

Although there is info on each of the other tabs (PHP Settings, Config File & Directory Permissions). Img included.

[image]

Tested on different browsers and cleared cache.

What would cause this and any suggestions on how to resolve? Possible hack? Everything else on the site seems to be working front end and back. I am able to ftp to the site and view the config.php file which again looks ok to me.

Joomla 3.3.0 No recent changes/installations made.

Comment: I assume you have set error reporting to `development`. If not, try doing so and report back any errors. On a side note, I would also suggest updating to 3.3.6

Comment: I hadn't @Lodder good idea, it's now set to development and only reporting a `Notice: Undefined offset: 0` on the Php Info page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that your server is configured to prevent the view of `phpinfo()`?

Check out your server php.ini to find the line saying `disable_functions = phpinfo`.

There you could remove the `phpinfo`-entry and try again.

UPDATE: just checked my guess on my local machine. The error message is the same:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /joomlahome/administrator/components/com_admin/models/sysinfo.php on line 174
```

So you can alter your `php.ini`, create a local one or ask your friendly administrator to do this for you. (see [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/243993)).

Comment: Thanks @lars I never thought of that. I will maybe add a phpinfo file to the root of my site and see what shows. I thought Joomla would have presented me with some sort of permissions error though if this were the case? Rather than show a blank screen.

Comment: Looking in the file `administrator/components/com_admin/models/sysinfo.php` on line 174 I see that there is noch check if the `phpinfo()` was successfully retrieved. When I check that with this `if (!phpinfo(INFO_GENERAL | INFO_CONFIGURATION | INFO_MODULES))` then the correct error message is thrown: `Warning: phpinfo() has been disabled for security reasons`. Without this check we have an empty string with a not existing offset of 0.

Comment: @larsk. Did you report the bug?

Comment: @VilleNiemi Nope. You think it should be?

Comment: If you actually found a part of code missing and adding it results in a correct and already existing error message... I'd say that is a bug and should be reported. And if you include a ready sample code to fix it, I am sure the developers will be very happy to receive that report.